# Linking errors Cython

Tags: c++, cython

I am trying to compile a simple "Hello World" program with cython and get a bunch of confusing linking errors.
The code is

```
# setupp.py
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(ext_modules = cythonize("hello_world.pyx"))
```

and

```
# hello_world.pyx
print("Hello World!")
```

I am compiling with

```
python setup.py built_ext --inplace
```

The errors I am getting are below. If anyone has suggestions on what could be the cause of these errors, it would be much appreciated!

> LIBCMT.lib(dll_dllmain.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external
> symbol _initterm
>
> LIBCMT.lib(dll_dllmain.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external
> symbol _initterm_e
>
> LIBCMT.lib(gs_report.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> __imp_RtlCaptureContext
>
> LIBCMT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external
> symbol __imp_RtlCaptureContext
>
> LIBCMT.lib(gs_report.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> __imp_RtlLookupFunctionEntry
>
> LIBCMT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external
> symbol __imp_RtlLookupFunctionEntry
>
> libvcruntime.lib(risctrnsctrl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved
> external symbol __imp_RtlLookupFunctionEntry
>
> LIBCMT.lib(gs_report.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> __imp_RtlVirtualUnwind
>
> LIBCMT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external
> symbol __imp_RtlVirtualUnwind
>
> LIBCMT.lib(gs_report.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> __imp_UnhandledExceptionFilter
>
> LIBCMT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external
> symbol __imp_UnhandledExceptionFilter
>
> LIBCMT.lib(gs_report.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> __imp_SetUnhandledExceptionFilter
>
> LIBCMT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external
> symbol __imp_SetUnhandledExceptionFilter
>
> LIBCMT.lib(gs_report.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> __imp_GetCurrentProcess
>
> LIBCMT.lib(gs_report.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> __imp_TerminateProcess
>
> LIBCMT.lib(gs_report.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> IsProcessorFeaturePresent
>
> LIBCMT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external
> symbol IsProcessorFeaturePresent
>
> LIBCMT.lib(gs_support.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> __imp_QueryPerformanceCounter
>
> LIBCMT.lib(gs_support.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> __imp_GetCurrentProcessId
>
> LIBCMT.lib(gs_support.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> __imp_GetCurrentThreadId
>
> LIBCMT.lib(gs_support.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> __imp_GetSystemTimeAsFileTime
>
> LIBCMT.lib(tncleanup.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> __imp_InitializeSListHead
>
> LIBCMT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> _seh_filter_dll
>
> LIBCMT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> _configure_narrow_argv
>
> LIBCMT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> _initialize_narrow_environment
>
> LIBCMT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> _initialize_onexit_table
>
> LIBCMT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> _register_onexit_function
>
> LIBCMT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> _execute_onexit_table
>
> LIBCMT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> _crt_atexit
>
> LIBCMT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> _crt_at_quick_exit
>
> LIBCMT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
> _cexit
>
> LIBCMT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external
> symbol __imp_IsDebuggerPresent
>
> LIBCMT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external
> symbol __imp_GetStartupInfoW
>
> LIBCMT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external
> symbol __imp_GetModuleHandleW
>
> LIBCMT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external
> symbol terminate
>
> libvcruntime.lib(ehhelpers.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external
> symbol terminate
>
> libvcruntime.lib(frame.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external
> symbol terminate
>
> libvcruntime.lib(riscchandler.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved
> external symbol __imp_RtlUnwindEx
>
> libvcruntime.lib(risctrnsctrl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved
> external symbol __imp_RtlUnwindEx

Comment: May I ask what OS are you running this on?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: Have you installed MSVC? You need it in order to compile anything with the standard C++ library. I'd say the error messages come from the compiler not finding this library.